# objective-c type encoding in printf / string with format in macro

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, printf

How can I create a string of any primitve values? Okay, structs etc might be a big problem.. But for floats, integers

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html

Note: this is strictly for debugging, unit tests and for *fun*!

Answer (score 1):

This covers the most basic.. I don't know if it is sufficient... Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious?

```
#define _PRIMITIVE_AS_STRING(value) \
({\
    const char *valueType = @encode(__typeof__(value));\
    NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", printFormatTypeForObjCType(valueType)];\
    NSString *valueAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, value];\
    valueAsString;\
})

static const char * printFormatTypeForObjCType(const char *type)
{
    if(strcmp(type, @encode(BOOL)) == 0)
        return "%d";
    else if(strcmp(type, @encode(int)) == 0)
        return "%d";
    else if(strcmp(type, @encode(unsigned int)) == 0)
        return "%u";
    else if(strcmp(type, @encode(long)) == 0)
        return "%li";
    else if(strcmp(type, @encode(unsigned long)) == 0)
        return "%lu";
    else if(strcmp(type, @encode(long long)) == 0)
        return "%lli";
    else if(strcmp(type, @encode(unsigned long long)) == 0)
        return "%llu";
    else if(strcmp(type, @encode(float)) == 0)
        return "%f";
    else if(strcmp(type, @encode(double)) == 0)
        return "%f";
    else
        return "%d";
}
```

Comment: `double` should be `%f`. `%d` is for integer types. `unsigned long` should be `%lu`. `unsigned long long` should be `%llu`. `unsigned int` can be just `%u`.